# How do I validate the total number of passed arguments?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

While using `argparse`, I need to make sure the user inputs two strings. However, there are two possible options for them to input the strings in, e.g. options `-a` and `-b`. They should be able to do any of the following:

```
python runscript.py -a str1 str2
python runscript.py -a str1 -b str2
python runscript.py -b str1 str2
```

The key is there must be only two inputs but that they can be for any of the options available.

My attempt basically sets the arguments like this

```
parser.add_argument('-a', nargs='*')
parser.add_argument('-b', nargs='*')
```

Then I  have to do this:

```
if (args.a): num_a = len(args.a)    # I need to check if the -a option was even used
else: num_a = 0

if (args.b): num_b = len(args.b)    # same as above but for -b option
else: num_b = 0

# Check that number of arguments is correct 
if (num_a + num_b) != 2:
    <error code>
```

This seems a little extraneous. Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: What meaning do `-a` and `-b` have that you can't simply define two positional arguments (or one positional argument with `nargs=2`)?

Comment: One way or other you have to sum the length of the args.  Nothing in `argparse` will do it for you.

Comment: @chepner I'm sure there are many cases where you might need that but for my case: I want the user to input two filenames to be compared. I need them to also specify what kind of files they are inputting as the filename extension can be arbitrary. So there's no way to know what kind of file the user is without explicitly telling me using options. Then depending on which file option they choose, I parse the file differently. i.e. there's two filetypes that contain similar information but formatted differently and I need to know which way to parse either filetype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give both arguments a default *empty* list value:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', nargs='*', default=[])
parser.add_argument('-b', nargs='*', default=[])
```

Now the value is *always* going to be a list, simplifying your error check:

```
if len(args.a) + len(args.b) != 2:
    parser.error('....')
```